# If the line integral of electric field across a loop is equal to 0, then why does the electric field across a closed circuit equal to its emf nd not 0

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

The line integral of electric field across a closed loop is equal to zero as electrostatic force is a conservative force. Then why it is equal to the EMF of the cell and not zero across a closed circuit.

Comment: The integral **is** zero if you go right round the circuit including through the battery.

Comment: @JohnRennie then how come it equal to EMF of the cell. Because EMF of the cell can't be zero.

Comment: integrating the field along a line between the poles from one pole to the other is not a closed loop but when you close it you get 0.

Comment: When you go from the -ve terminal through the battery to the +ve terminal the potential rises by $E$. Then when you go from the +ve terminal through the external circuit and back to the -ve terminal the potential falls by $E$. So the change right round the circuit is $E - E = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Circulation of electric field along a conductive path in a DC circuit (with constant current) is zero:

$$
\oint_{circuit} \mathbf E\cdot d\mathbf s = 0.
$$
The battery in the circuit does not change that. It acts on the charge carriers when they are inside the battery via additional macroscopic force $\mathbf E^*$, which is separate force from the macroscopic electric field $\mathbf E$. This additional force is present only in the battery: it pushes charge against force due to macroscopic electric field $\mathbf E$ and does the work (converting chemical energy into electric potential energy). It is the force of the battery, causing the battery to have non-zero EMF.

The battery contribution to EMF can be expressed as

$$
\mathscr{E}_{battery} = \oint_{circuit} \mathbf E^*\cdot d\mathbf s = \int_{negative~terminal}^{positive~terminal}\mathbf E^* \cdot d\mathbf s.
$$
since outside the battery, $\mathbf E^*$ vanishes.